# Spark Recommendations using ALS

Tags: apache-spark, collaborative-filtering

so I am constructing a recommedation model using ALS package And make all user-product list by cartesian product. And I finally predict all the ratings. But I want to group the ratings by users. and the final format used to be (user, (product, ratings)) and i have to sort by decending order.

THIS IS MY CODE

```
val ratings = sc.textFile(new File("/user/ubuntu/kang/0829/rawRatings.csv").toString).map { line =>
  val fields = line.split(",")
  (Rating(fields(0).toInt,fields(1).toInt,fields(2).toDouble))}
  val model = ALS.train(ratings,10,10,0.1)
   val numUsers = ratings.map(_.user).distinct
   val numMovies = ratings.map(_.product).distinct
   val usersProducts = numUsers.cartesian(numMovies)
   val recommendations = model.predict(usersProducts)
```

BUT IN HERE value recommendations is not a Pair-RDD and it's a Rating(_)format 
so I cannot apply groupByKey...

Could anybody solve this problem...?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
recommendations.map (x => (x.user, (x.product, x.rating))).reduceByKey(here put reduce function)
```